# Stuck on EntityFramework update-database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

For a ton of times I have used `entity framework core` and code-first migrations it's the first time I'm stuck.

In my project, everything is running in docker so is my database.
I exposed port 1433 so I was able to externally use ssms <- this works i can connect with a user.

When I try to do update-database to push my migrations I got the error login failed:  container_id\guest.

Now I'm wondering why it tries to connect with container_id and guest user while sa is specified in the connectionstring.
The default project is my API endpoint which contains my application context class as well as my migrations.

question: Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: MSSQLServer
    ports:
    - "1433:1433" 
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: ${Api_SA_PASSWORD}
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        

  portfolio-frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}portfoliofrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Portfolio-frontend/Dockerfile

  apiendpoint:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiendpoint
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: HeaderInfoApi/Dockerfile


"ConnectionStrings": {
"ApplicationContext": "Server=server;Database=Portfolio;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User=username;Password=password"
```

}

connetionstring in appsettings, in appsettings.development my real secrets are filled in which should override appsettings if i'm correct.

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

I also have this in my application builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the `Integrated Security=false` part of your connection string that needs to be there.

```
Data Source=.;Database=myDb;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=<password>
```

Comment: i fiex the issue apparently it's the server its not localhost but the ip address of your computer which i found in another thread